# How can I fix voice dialing iCloud contacts?

Tags: iphone, icloud, voice-dictation

I use voice dialing primarily to call my wife, let's call her "Helga". She's the only Helga in my contacts, so I could hold the button and say "call Helga mobile" and it would dial her iPhone.

Since I updated her phone to iOS5 (and enabled iCloud), when I say "call Helga mobile" my phone asks me which of four Helgas I wish to dial -- my wife or one of the three other Helgas in *her* contact list.

I've disable iCloud contact syncing on my phone but not yet on hers. If I go to http://www.icloud.com/, I can only use "Find my iPhone" there.

What else can I do?

Comment: To understand this right: You've upgraded *her* phone and if you call her from *your* phone it picks contacts from *her* contact list?

Comment: I've upgrade both of our phones to iOS5. It doesn't matter if I'm trying to call her on her mobile or home phone numbers, it offers contacts from *her* contact list.

Comment: I assume you already verified in your contacts that the Helgas are not there. Are you sharing your AppleID with your wife?

Comment: Let's separate all the problems here: We don't care about her phone. I think you did something wrong somewhere. Check that you have your own iCloud account and your wife her own. You shouldn't share one account. Then have a look at your address book and check if some contacts haven't been duplicated.

Comment: @patrix - my wife is the only Helga in my phone's contact list.

Comment: @Coyote - Yes, shared iCloud account because we have a shared iTunes account. I'll see if I can figure out how to separate now that the damage has been done.

Comment: @DougHarris - there is no need to share the iCloud account along with the iTunes (Store) account. You can easily just share the iTunes account while having individual iCloud accounts.

Comment: Stop using the shared iCloud account and create one iCloud account each. Use the shared account for iTunes Store only...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new contact name for your wife's iPhone number.  "Call Mary's mobile".

Comment: That would work but it's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the phonetic fields to write the name in a manner that your iPhone understands. I do that with the contacts I call the most.